# correct import of core-js when using useBuiltins entry and browserslist

Tags: webpack, babeljs, core-js

My webpack.config is adding `core-js/stable` and `regenerator-runtime/runtime` to the webpack config entry property:

```
const config = {
    name: 'client',
    target: 'web',
    entry: ['core-js/stable', 'regenerator-runtime/runtime', 'src/index'],
```

My babel config is using `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`

and I have the following `.browserslistrc`

```
>0.25%, not dead
```

My bundle size still looks pretty huge, I have highlighted the core-js bits in the webpack analyzer image below

[image]

Does babel use the `browserslistrc` when `useBuiltins` is set to `entry` and is there anyway I can tell that only the relevant bits of core-js are imported?

Answer (score 0):

1. bundle size still looks pretty huge cause `>0.25%, not dead` need lot of polyfill.
2. set to `usage` tell that only build relevant polyfill.